# Java Chromium Embeded 3 (JCEF3) mobile version emulation

Tags: java, user-agent

I would like to write java application using jcef3 and emulate that as mobile browser.

I do somethink like that:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onBeforeResourceLoad(CefBrowser cefBrowser, CefRequest cefRequest) {
        Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> newHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        cefRequest.getHeaderMap(headerMap);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headerMap.entrySet())
        {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("User-Agent")) {
                newHeaderMap.put(entry.getKey(), "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.114 Mobile Safari/537.36");
            } else {
                newHeaderMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        cefRequest.setHeaderMap(newHeaderMap);

        return false;
    }
```

Problem is with that one page that I would like browse like mobile detect that is some strange OS :) and I don't know why. If I download some plugin form chrome like user agent switcher and use the same UA then everything is ok, so I'm sure that that page use user agent verification.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved that problem.

Generaly there are two ways to detect browser.
First one is request headers. My sample code show how to do that.
The secound one is javascript navigator property. That was the problem. Requests were sended with correct userAgent but javascript navigator.userAgent show bad user agent version that was different with that sended in request headers.
To do that correctly You should override javascript navigator.userAgent variable.
In CEF3 there is no problem with that to inject some javascript code that override that.

Comment: Hi, I am working on jcef3 implementation and come across your post. Do you have any idea that how we can inject javascript in CefRequest when loading a a URL in onBeforeResourceLoad. I want to add javascript on each loaded html page and looking a way in jcef3.